# How to remove strings inside brackets?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have list of words and I have to remove list of strings inside the brackets

```
day[1.0,264.0]
developers[1.0,264.0]
does[1.0,264.0]
employees[1.0,264.0]
ex[1.0,264.0]
experts[1.0,264.0]
fil[1.0,264.0]
from[1.0,264.0]
gr[1.0,264.0]
```

I should get

```
day

developers

does
.
.
.
.
```

Is this approach correct?

```
String rep=day[1.0,264.0];  
String replaced=rep.replace("[","]","1.0","2");
```

or

this approach is correct?

```
Pattern stopWords = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:i|[|]|1|2|3|...)\\b\\s*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);    
Matcher matcher = stopWords.matcher("I would like to do a nice novel about nature AND people");    
String clean = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

Comment: Try yourself to know which variant works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly simpler approach than the others suggested so far.

```
String s = "day[1.0,264.0]";
String ofInterest2 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("["));
```

Will give you the output

```
day
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**String#replaceAll(regex, repl)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
 String rep="day[1.0,264.0]";
 rep = rep.replaceAll("\\[.*]","");
```

regex:`\\[.*]` as `[` is a special character (meta chacrater) in regex world you have to escape it will backslash to treat it as a literal.`.*` is for anything in b/w '[anything here]'

Answer (score 1):

Just replace them with nothing

```
rep.replaceAll("\\[.*\\]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tokenize your string by "[" and get the first part.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "[");
String part1 = st.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows for stuff after the brackets as well

```
     String rep="day[1.0,264.0]";
     int firstIndex = rep.indexOf('[');
     int secondIndex = rep.indexOf(']');
     String news = rep.substring(0, firstIndex) +    rep.substring(secondIndex+1,rep.length());
```